# pass argument to Express route/module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express server that creates a WSS server like so:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: '8080' });

wss.on('connection', async (ws, req) => { 
 ...
})

// routes setup
const chatRouter = require('./routes/chatPoint')(wss);

app.use('/api/chat', chatRouter);
```

I am attempting to pass argument 'wss" to the following module:

```
router.patch('/title', jsonParser, async (req, res) => {
   ...
});

module.exports = router;
```

The current error that I am getting is:

```
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#app.locals). Set a property and you'll be able to access it from the `request` object as `req.app.locals` from any middleware.

Comment: how would I pass to or just access app.locals.wss in module?

Comment: @PetarIvcec `app.locals.wss = wss`.

Comment: I've tried that, but doing:  ```router.patch('/title', jsonParser, async (req, res) => {
  console.log('wss', app.locals.wss);...``` gives me "app not defined"

Comment: ```console.log('req.app.locals.wss', req.app.locals.wss);``` gives me access to wss inside route module. Thanks :)